# Combining two modules without making the factory a god object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, module, decorator

We have an application that contacts several diffrent remote services(SOAP, HTTPREQUEST). We then do different actions(import, export, update, delete).

Today we have **two client classes** and **four action classes**.

**QUESTION!**
How can I decouple these two modules so that I have to do the least changes. IE only add a new action/new client. Nothing more.

**Client class**
Authorizes our client against the remote service, it handles logging in and out.

**Action class**
Holds the url, method to invoke against the client. Aswell as the ExecuteActionMethod

**Usage**
Client class get's decorated with an action and then performs the action with the client.

**Fears**
I dont want to: 
 - create a new **action class** everytime I add a new **client class** 
 - create a new **client class** everytime I add a new **action class** 
 - No god object factory that needs to know everything

**Problem**
The problem with this approach is that when talking to different clients, I need diffrent information in this case different URLS, talking to the Soap service needs invoking of the correct method. **The action itself is the keeper of this information. But as I dig deeper this certainly is something that will change.**

**Scenario 1#**
I end up creating classes that combine both action and result. So I have classes like "HttpImport"(based on HttpClient and ImportAction). Which results in **X(Clients) * Y(Actions)** which now would **total at 8 classes**, which is really bad.

**Scenario 2#**
Time for some code! In this scenario the implementation binds my classes together even though I use abstractions.

Problem here is that every action need to have a property for each of the clients(remember they visit different endpoints). So if i were to add one more **client** I would have to go through all the actions and add another property for that clients endpoint, aswell as add another deocrator to delegete all calls to the correct endpoint(remember i have three properties now in every action). If I were to create another action, it would just be that action. So N*times actions + 1(the action), **in this case 5 changes**. A little bit better but still not there.

**Scenario 3#**
This is the God object factory. Here we get rid of the properties holding the endpoints, and we supply the enpoint via the constructor. This will result in methods for creating all sorts of clients and actions. Same as above **X(Clients) * Y(Actions)** if something were to be added, these accumulate **into 8 new methods inside the factory**. The factory must also hold endpoint information.

**Code**
My code has evolved to the 2:nd scenario. I dont want to build the factory, and I'm looking to you guys.

Something tells me that the client classes does to much and should somehow be decoupled, from the classes they instansiate inside.

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        IAction iact = new ImportAction();
        IDecorator idec = new HttpDecorator(iact);
        IClient icli = new HttpClient(idec);

        Console.Write(icli.connect().ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**IAction**

```
public interface IAction
{
    string[] Execute();
    string HttpString { get; }
    string SoapMethod { get; }
}
```

**ImportAction**

```
class ImportAction : IAction
{
    private string soapmethod;
    private string httpUrl;
    public ImportAction()
    {
        this.HttpString = @"http://www.hereiswereactionsgo.com";
    }   
    public string[] Execute()
    {   //Execute the action!
        return null;
    }
    public string HttpString { get; set; }
    public string SoapMethod { get; set; }
}
```

**IDecorator**

```
public interface IDecorator
{
    string GetActionString();
}
```

**HttpDecorator**

```
class HttpDecorator : IDecorator
{
    private IAction _action;
    public HttpDecorator(IAction action)
    {
        this._action = action;
    }
    public string GetActionString()
    {
        return _action.HttpString;
    }
    public string[] Execute()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**IClient**

```
public interface IClient
{
    bool connect();
}
```

**HttpClient**

```
class HttpClient : IClient
{
    private string _username;
    private string _password;
    private IDecorator _myaction;
    private HttpWebRequest webReq;

    public HttpClient(IDecorator action)
    {
        this._username = "myusername";
        this._password = "mypassword";
        this._myaction = action;   
    }

    public bool connect()
    {
        bool result = false;
        webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_myaction.GetActionString());
        webReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password);
        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

        if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Visitor** pattern seems suitable for this ([Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)) .
Treat Actions as the Visitors and Clients as Elements to visit. Keeping Action as an abstract class rather than interface may help by providing the boilerplate code.

- To add a new Action extend `BaseAction`. Implement methods such as `getHttpUrl()`, `getHttpBody()` etc.
- To add a new Client will require changes to existing classes. You have to implement corresponding methods in each Action class. I assume adding a new Client will happen less frequently.

The sample code below follows Java syntax.

```
public static void main() {
  new HttpClient().performAction(new ImportAction());
}

public interface Client {
  performAction(Action);
}

public class HttpClient implements Client {
  public void accept(IAction a) {
    a.visitHttp(this);
  }
}

public abstract class Action {
  public visitHttp(HttpClient c) {
     getHttpUrl();
     c.connect(getHttpUrl());
     c.send(getHttpBody());
     c.close;
  }

  public visitSoap(SoapClient c) {

  }

  public abstract String getHttpUrl();
  public abstract String getHttpBody();
}

ImportAction extends Action {
  @Override
  getHttpUrl() {

  }

  @Override
  getHttpBody() {

  }
}
```